# как отображать элементы listView наоборот

Tags: android, android-fragment, listview

есть listView, и когда добавляешь элемент через адаптер, этот элемент добавляется в конец списка (вниз). Можно ли как то добавлять элементы в начало, то есть  вверх?
Сам listView:

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoiceModal"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
```

В MainActivity:

```
private fun refreshData(){
    lstNotes=db.allNotes
    var intent = Intent(this, write_activity::class.java)
    val adapter=ListNoteAdapter(this, lstNotes, new_note, intent, this)
    grid.adapter=adapter
}
```

В Adapter:

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    val rowView:View
    rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.note_view, null)

    rowView.note.setText(lstNotes[position].notes_name)

    rowView.setOnClickListener {
        intent.putExtra("transition_text", lstNotes[position].note)
        startActivity(context, intent, null)
    }
    return rowView
}
```

Comment: я что-то так и не понял, а как Вы сейчас добавляете элемент? Приведите код, как Вы сейчас пытаетесь это сделать, тогда будет понятно, с чем именно трудности.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov добавляю через адаптер, в коде из mainActivity, там строчка grid.adapter=adapter, код из адаптера есть, я имею ввиду, что по умолчанию элементы в listview (как и gridview, gridlayout и т.д) добавляются вниз, тоесть сверху пользователь видит старые элементы, а внизу новые, мне нужно наоборот

Comment: Вы когда добавляете элемент в список, делаете это примерно так `list.add(element);` для добавления в начало списка нужно сделать так `list.add(0, element);` Сейчас у Вас нет кода добавления элементов, есть только код первичной инициализации списка

Comment: можно добавлять в любом порядке заполняя данные в адаптере

Answer (score 0):

В прямом порядке - adapter.add(object);
В обратном - adapter.insert(object,0);

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь давать более развёрнутые ответы, ответ на вопрос должен быть **исчерпывающим**. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Ответ можно отредактировать кнопкой «[править](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1517566/edit)».